# T-SQL split column based on delimiter and input the split string array into multiple table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Looking to split string within a column based on a the same delimiter multiple times and input each string array into separate table columns within the same table e.g.

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(50)
SET @Test = '0^5^6^104^0^0^5'
```

**Expected output**

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7
0 5 6 104 0 0 5
```

Comment: Please do not store list of values as a delimited string. This will cause huge performance issues. Lookup any number examples involving splitters with dynamic pivot

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test table (val VARCHAR(50))
insert into @Test (val)values  ('0^5^6^104^0^0^5')




;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT   
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([val], '^', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  @Test) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
     Select [1]Col1,[6]Col2,[7]Col3,[4]Col1,[2]Col1,[3]Col1,[5]Col1 from (
     select T.RN,T.String from (
     select Row_number()OVER( ORDER BY string )RN,string from CTE)T)K
     PIVOT(MAX(string) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]))P
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(50)
SET @Test = '0^5^6^104^0^0^5'

select * from (
select t.col.value('.','varchar(max)') as val, 'column' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) as varchar(10)) as rn from
    (
        select cast('<m>' + REPLACE(@test,'^','</m><m>') + '</m>' as xml) as val
    ) as abc
    cross apply abc.val.nodes('/m') as t(col)
              ) as t1
              pivot (max(val) for rn in (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7)) as pvt
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(50)
SET @Test = '0^5^6^104^0^0^5'
SET @Test = N'SELECT N''' + REPLACE(@Test,'^',''' ,''') + ''''
exec(@Test)
```

Comment: People are giving negative comments to other Users post without knowing what have written or without even testing the code. Once after the author replied, the commented person removed the comment without revoking the negative point. This hurts.